# How I got IntelliJ IDEA code Center Aligned?

Tags: intellij-idea

The code stays in center like `Distraction Free Mode` any idea where this setting can be found can't seem to find it again?

[image]

Comment: How did you get into this state? Make sure `editor.distraction.free.mode` is not enabled in Registry: https://i.imgur.com/Vc3KSLu.png. See also [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002#focus=streamItem-27-3499314.0-0) in a related issue.

Comment: Interesting I was actually in `distraction free mode` but it doesn't actually hide everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

The issue was that `Distraction Free Mode` was enabled and then at the same time I enabled the option in `Settings > Appearance > Appearance & Behavior` toggled `Show tool window bars` which actually made them visible in `Distraction Free Mode` but disabled them in `Normal mode`.

***What I learned from this?***

*So there are two modes and they can be both managed separately.*

Answer (score 3):

There is a fix for this now:

> IntelliJ IDEA now offers a setting under Settings > Advanced Settings > Left margin in distraction free mode. Set it to 0 to achieve the desired result.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134555/Distraction-free-mode-the-left-margin-is-too-wide#focus=Comments-27-6085156.0-0